# Python - Why 2 different functions identify the same tuple as <class 'tuple'> while another function identifies the same tuple as None

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, tuples, nonetype

So when I call

```
plot_bounces( ball, numbounces, boxWH_tuple, circle=None )
```

where ball is an object, numbounces is an int, boxWH_tuple and circle are tuples, and put a `print(type(circle))` statement in this function, it is a tuple. However, when I call `update_ball(ball, boxWH_tuple, circle=None)` an put a `print(type(circle))` statement in this function, it is a nonetype. I don't understand why nor how to make it a tuple for both functions. This is just part of my code which seems to be problematic.

This is what I used to call plot_bounces

```
plot_bounces(Ball(-1,0,0.1), 1, (3,2), ( (0,0) ,0.4) )
```

There's another script with class Ball which deals with the Ball object.

My main concern is why `print(type(circle))` gives me class 'tuple' for the first print and class 'NoneType' for the second print.

```
def plot_bounces(ball, numbounces, boxWH_tuple, circle=None):
    print(type (circle))
     #make space to store coordinates 
    xcoords = []
    ycoords = []
    #store the starting point 
    xcoords.append(ball.x)
    ycoords.append(ball.y)


    while numbounces>0 :
        #calls on update_ball and change the old values with new ones 

        update_ball(ball, boxWH_tuple, circle=None)
#       
        ball=update_ball(ball, boxWH_tuple, circle=None)

        xpoint = ball.x
        ypoint = ball.y

        ycoords.append(ypoint)
        xcoords.append(xpoint)

        numbounces+= -1


def update_ball(ball, boxWH_tuple, circle=None):
    print (type(circle))
```

Should't it be a tuple for both cases?

Comment: `None` is a separate type in Python. You are passing `circle=None`, the type is `nonetype`

Comment: You call `update_ball( ..., circle=None)`. You should be calling: `update_ball(ball, boxWH_tuple, circle)` in both cases.

Comment: Still no difference on my end though, unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `update_ball()` from `plot_bounces()`, please remove `=None` after circle,
because when you do `circle=None` in a call (call, not function definition), then you are passing that argument as a None and therefore the confusion.

The call should be `update_ball(ball, boxWH_tuple, circle)`